# java Compare two dates

Tags: java, date

I want to compare two dates and check if the date has expired or not.

Here is the code I used :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss:ii");
Date date1 = sdf.parse("20012-10-4 10:15:25");
Date date2 = sdf.parse("2013-10-4 10:15:25");

if(date1.equals(date12)){
    System.out.println("Both are equals");
}
```

I want to check the two dates but without success.

I also tried to check it like that :

```
if(date1 >= date2){
    System.out.println("Both are not equals");
}
```

But it's not working either.

Comment: Have you read the javadoc? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29

Comment: yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss:ii is not valid. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: [REFERENCE](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

java.util.Date class has before and after method to compare dates.

```java
Date date1 = new Date();
Date date2 = new Date();

if(date1.before(date2)){
    //Do Something
}

if(date1.after(date2)){
    //Do Something else
}
```

Comment: How to check whether the **date1** is 10 minutes less than **date2**?

Comment: Hi How to check if Date is Less than equal to, I can check less than using before api?

Answer (score 5):

Try using this Function.It Will help You:-

```
public class Main {   
public static void main(String args[]) 
 {        
  Date today=new Date();                     
  Date myDate=new Date(today.getYear(),today.getMonth()-1,today.getDay());
  System.out.println("My Date is"+myDate);    
  System.out.println("Today Date is"+today);
  if(today.compareTo(myDate)<0)
     System.out.println("Today Date is Lesser than my Date");
  else if(today.compareTo(myDate)>0)
     System.out.println("Today Date is Greater than my date"); 
  else
     System.out.println("Both Dates are equal");      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Read `JavaDocs`.

Use method:

```
 Date.compareTo()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look at compareTo function of Date class.

[JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
date1.before(date2);
```

or:

```
date1.after(date2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You [equals(Object o)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) comparison is correct.

Yet, you should use [after(Date d)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29) and [before(Date d)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29) for date comparison.