# Compare Start and End Date Android

Tags: android, date, compare

I have two functions wherein it lets the user set a particular date. It's Start Date and End Date. Now I need to
compare these two variables because the Start Date should not be greater than the End Date.  Here's my code in android. Any help will do. Thanks.

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
{
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        yr = year;
        month = monthOfYear;
        day = dayOfMonth;
        Date.setText((month + 1) + "/" + day + "/" + yr);
    }
};

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener1 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
{
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view1, int year1, int monthOfYear1, int dayOfMonth1)
    {
        yr = year1;
        month = monthOfYear1;
        day = dayOfMonth1;

        DateEnd.setText((month + 1) + "/" + day + "/" + yr);
    }
};
```

Comment: Please avoid duplicate questions....Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15925576/1765530

Answer (score 0):

You can check this by following code.

```
if (mDateSetListener.before(mDateSetListener1) || Code.DueDate.equals(Code.AssignDate)) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilderDate = new AlertDialog.Builder(Assignment_Create_Ext_DB.this);
    alertDialogBuilderDate.setTitle("Date assigning issue");
    alertDialogBuilderDate
    .setMessage("Due date can not be equal or less then the Assign date")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    alertDialogBuilderDate.show();
}
```

Comment: as stated `mDateSetListener.before(mDateSetListener1)` you can also use `mDateSetListener.after(mDateSetListener1)` if you want to set date after.

Answer (score 0):

Following is my code to compare two dates,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

String startDate = tvStartDate.getText().toString().trim(); 
String endDate = tvEndDate.getText().toString().trim();

startDate = startDate.substring( startDate.indexOf( ":" ) + 1 ); 
endDate = endDate.substring( endDate.indexOf( ":" ) + 1 );

Date startDat = sdf.parse(startDate); 
Date endDat = sdf.parse(endDate);

if ( startDat.compareTo(endDat) <= 0 )
{
     // ok
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start date must be lesser than or equal to End Date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your date string to date object as:

```
 try{       
                SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat.getValue(),locale); 
                Date d1 = curFormater.parse(dateStr); 
Date d2 = curFormater.parse(dateStr2); 

//Now just compare the two dates as

if(d1.before(d2)){
}
else{
}
            }catch (Exception e) {
                LogHandler.error(tag, "getDataFormate", e);
                return null;
            }
```

Let me know if it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
    boolean compareTime(int startDay, int startMonth, int startYear,
        int monthDay, int month, int year) {
    Time timeNow = new Time();
    Time timeSelected = new Time();

    timeNow.set(startDay, startMonth, startYear);

    timeSelected.set(monthDay, month, year);

    long millisNow = timeNow.toMillis(true);
    long millisSelected = timeSelected.toMillis(true);

    long diff = millisSelected - millisNow;
    long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);

    Log.i(TAG, "diffHours = " + diffHours);

    if (diffHours <= 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```