# Compare two date of type String

Tags: java, date

i have in my DB a date in this format 2016-03-11 09:20:22
how i can do if i want to compare with today date?
I try to make this but i think that is not efficient:

```
private int getDayOfYear(String dateString) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
        GregorianCalendar greg = new GregorianCalendar();
        greg.setTime(date);
        return greg.get(greg.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }
    private int getMonth(String dateString) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
        GregorianCalendar greg = new GregorianCalendar();
        greg.setTime(date);
        return greg.get(greg.MONTH);
    }
    private int getYear(String dateString) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
        GregorianCalendar greg = new GregorianCalendar();
        greg.setTime(date);
        return greg.get(greg.YEAR);
    }
```

Now i apply on today date and on db date this method, there is another way to compare two date?

Comment: Also a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19109960/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15925509/642706) and others. Please search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date)) method:

```
date1.compareTo(date2);
```

There are other methods as well like [before](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29) or [after](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29) which you can use for Dates.

Comment: Doesn't this make it so the same date but different times are different? Didn't see anything on the documentation for that.

Comment: @dquijada:- It will take care of the time as well if the date is same.

Comment: But as I understand she wants to compare only dates, not times. Might be wrong tho.

Comment: @dquijada:- I went with the first and the last line which says: `i have in my DB a date in this format 2016-03-11 09:20:22 how i can do if i want to compare with today date?` and the part `there is another way to compare two date?`

Comment: @dquijada if so `SimpleDateFormat` should be `yyyy-MM-dd` but this is the correct way to compare dates

Comment: Notice that she only returns day of month, month and year. She probably copied the date format stuff from some other example.

Comment: dates to be compared are of type String